# I'm looking for a specific replacement PCB module connector

Tags: pcb, connector, pcb-assembly

I wonder of anyone here may be able to help. I've been looking for some time now for a replacement for an old (c. 1980s or early 1990s) PCB module *connector*. I'm looking for anything similar in order to connect these modules to the PCB. I've tried looking for the part no. and also tried image searching. What I am trying to do is connect these modules to updated and modified PCBs, but to do that I need to find a similar connector type.

[image: PCB module connector]

The actual connector.

[image: Opto-isolator Module]

The module.

[image: Connector terminal Block]

Detail of connector showing terminal block.

If anyone can help me identify and find a replacement for this connector, I should be very grateful. Many thanks!

Comment: It looks proprietary. They may have used such a custom connector in part to discourage what you are trying to do. Possibly there are more markings that are hidden under the connector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you really sure you searched for everything?

((EDIT: I do not mean to be mean there ^^, I just meant: Searching can mean a multi-stage process))

First search for ["Siemens NTIO" brought this](https://www.remotecenter.dk/datablade/pdf/K21-06.50.pdf) in the top 3 results.

Which then as a document name and unit descriptor has a full Siemens internal product series number (K21-06.50) and the identification of "NKOD"/"NKODH" and "NKID"/"NKIDH".

Searching for those letters and/or internal product numbers leads me toward a myriad of websites with names like "http://www.hobbielektronika.hu/", hosting PDFs about modules or connectors. This particular website seems to sell a load of stuff, but I can't read it. But if they have the PDFs, chances are they have something or will likely know (e-mail or call!) how or where to get stuff.

It does seem to be a Landis & Staefa proprietary internal type, but with 100's of websites particularly pointing at repair or hobby use, I'm betting in any corner of the world there's going to be a few. Since I don't know which languages you speak, the last half of that path is up to you.

As a first hint, [these people seem reasonably professional](http://www.acmetechnical.co.uk/Systems_siemens.html) and have a lot of stuff in similar series, they hosted a NKODH module PDF in the first search I did after the PDF, which also showed the NTIO module connected to it.

---

### Same EDIT as above:

I also opened an RS-Online which came up in the search, they have a lot of visually similar Siemens stuff. I had a meeting so I posted before I walked all tabs. But I hate their website, so I didn't try to find anything there, but you could try to.

---